# Why not ask to save password in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, browser

IE 11 version : 11.0.115

if add eventListner to username or password element,

Do not ask me about saving password in IE11

How do i fix it ?

```
  <form id="logintest" action="./test.html" method="POST">
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" />
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: stop using old broken browsers :p

Comment: Should it even ask you to save? I've not used IE in quite a while, so I don't know if it is supposed to save your credentials.

Comment: @VLAZ There's a setting in Internet Options for it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, then my question for OP is - is the option selected?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Select the gear on the right side of the main toolbar and choose “Internet Options“.
3. Select the “Content” tab, then select “Settings” in the “AutoComplete” section.
4. In the “Use AutoComplete for” pane, do one of the following:
5. Uncheck the “Ask me before saving passwords” box to stop IE from prompting you to save passwords. Passwords will still be saved on some occasions. Check the box if you wish to be prompted for saving passwords.
6. Uncheck the “User names and passwords on forms” to completely prevent IE from saving usernames and passwords. Check the box to enable it. You may also want to select “Delete AutoComplete history…” if you wish to clear any passwords IE has already saved.
7. Select “OK“. Close and restart Internet Explorer for the changes to take effect.